# How do a gather data in this DataFrame situation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm still relatively new to Python and Pandas.  I have a function which takes a dataframe df and a header column h and should return a dataframe derived from the original df as follows.

[jest showing the relevant columns of the input df below]

| KEY | Colors |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "yellow|blue|green" |
| 3 | orange |
| 4 | NA |

[formatting above is weird.  Colors column includes pipe-delimited values ]

Returns dataframe:

| KEY | Colors |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | yellow |
| 1 | blue |
| 1 | green |
| 3 | orange |
| 4 | NA |

I've got the pipe split sorted out.  But creating the new dataframe is not looking pretty.
I'm positive there's a more efficient way - the 'python way' - than what I've been doing.

[too embarrassed to show existing code]

Comment: No reason to be embarrassed about your existing code, please add it so that people can make relevant suggestions.  How else can one learn?  After all this site does rely on a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a starting point.

Comment: Without seeing the code there is not enough information to help you identify the changes you need to get it working.